# Appending String to Log File

Tags: c++, iostream

Below are the function and the call line.  I have a char sKey.  If within the IDE, if i inspect the tmpstring after converting it to a string, it shows the value i expect "E2247410849FA3".  But, when i view the log file, i get "003BFA34"  I want it to show the 722....  What am i doing wrong?

```
void logit(const std::string& ctext)
 {
     std::ofstream outfile;
     outfile.open("c:\\hex.log", std::ios_base::app |  std::ios_base::out);
     outfile << &ctext <<endl;
 }

tmpstring = std::string(sKey,14);
logit(tmpstring);
```

Comment: try in run mode in the ide once,

Comment: You should pass `ctext` by constant reference instead of by value. `const std::string& ctext`.

Comment: Thank you.  I made that modification, however it still had no effect on the result within the file.  The result is 0037FC0C this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have you append settings correct, but your code has one fatal flaw:

You are printing the memroy address of the string, not the actual string.

In order to rectify this, just pring `ctext` instead of `&ctext`:

```
void logit(std::string ctext)
 {
     std::ofstream outfile;
     outfile.open("c:\\hex.log", std::ios_base::app |  std::ios_base::out);
     outfile << ctext <<endl;
     //         ^ no &
 }
```

On a completely unrelated performance note, you should probally pass by const ref.

Comment: Thank you.  However - If i remove that, i then get the following error : Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Found problem.  Did not include  #include <string>

Comment: @iBoston Preprocessor statements such as `#include` don't need to end with a semi-colon. After, they're not exactly part of the language